# jquery slideup doesn't work

Tags: jquery, slideup

Why doesn't my jquery slideup work?
Related code:

```
<article id="slide1">article</article>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slide1").slideUp(3000);
});
</script>
```

The problem seems to be in my css
Can anyone help me figure out what the problem may is?

```
body {
    margin:0; 
    width:375px;
    background:#fff;
    font-family: arial; 
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    height: 640px;
    width: 375px;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 375px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #85d134;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0.96;
```

}

```
.width {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f46q9mnf/)

Comment: Do you not have content or a closing `article` tag? There's not enough here to help you.

Comment: Show all the relevant code please.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s8340f81/

Comment: (1) You're missing the closing `</article>`. (2) `.slideUp()` works by animating the element's `height` CSS property value from `n` to 0 where `n` is a number ***greater*** than 0. If you're `height` is already 0, there's nothing to _"slide up"_...

Comment: Thanks @j08691 that means there is something really wrong in my css code and of course i have a closing tag.. I just posted related information like the name of the id, to catch the problem quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of left-to-right (based on above clarifications re: the `</article>` closing tag)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slide1").animate({ 'margin-left': 100}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

close tag `</article>` html

```
<article id="slide1">article</article>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slide1").slideUp(3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: everyone knows this error code. think before commenting

Comment: Not sure what you mean by error code? All I was saying is that it seems coincidental that everything down to the way the HTML is formatted is exactly the same as the jsfiddle...